# Docusign C# SDK , Update Recipient and its custom fields

Tags: docusignapi

I am updating email of the recipient using C# docusign SDK. I am calling  envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients method but It is not updating custom fields with new values that I am providing by setting recipient.CustomFields Property.
**Signer or Carbon Copy recipients has property like CustomFields. I want to update that field. That field is not updated when I am calling updaterecipient method.**

```
 var singer = new Signer() { RecipientId = input.OldEnvelopeRecipientID };
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eEmail))
                        {
                            singer.SigningGroupId = entityID;
                            singer.Name = fullName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            singer.Email = eEmail;
                            singer.Name = fullName;
                        }

                        singer.CustomFields = DigitalCustomFieldHelper.GenerateCustomFields(customFieldsModel);
                        
                        recipeints.Signers.Add(singer);
```

**Update Method**

```
 public RecipientsUpdateSummary UpdateRecipients(string envelopeId, Recipients recipients, bool resend = false)
            {
                CheckToken();
    
    
                
 EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
               
 var result = envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(AccountID, envelopeId, recipients: recipients,
                  new EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions() { resendEnvelope = resend.ToString() });
    
                   
 SaveDigitalSigningLogEntry(envelopeId, "UpdateRecipients", DateTime.Now, data: result.ToJson());
                    return result;
    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recipient custom fields can only be updated on the initial POST call, when envelope is created. the PUT call for Recipients does not update them. It may be a bug, I'll check, it may be by design. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks Ibrar, But I don't want to update envelope custom fields . I am looking for updating Recipient custom fields.

Comment: Following line is not updating previous custom fields .singer.CustomFields = DigitalCustomFieldHelper.GenerateCustomFields(customFieldsModel);

Comment: not sure what you mean by "recipient custom fields". Maybe you just means tabs? the signing elements/fields for each recipient?

Comment: Signer or Carbon Copy recipients has property like CustomFields. I want to update that field. That field is not updated when I am calling updaterecipient method.

Comment: I don't want to get list of tabs . I just want to update Custom Fields property inside Signer. Please share some code.

Comment: the "custom fields" of a signer are called tabs. I think that's what you mean.

Comment: no there are separate fields for Tabs and customFields.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, let me update my answer Samee

Comment: Thanks a lot @Inbar . Kindly tell me if there is any rest API endpoint for updating custom fields for signer? I can write code to call it using c# if not present in SDK.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be an SDK issue. The eSign API does not seem to support it, but I'm not sure yet if that's a bug or a designed behavior. I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign confirmed it is a bug in DocuSign API (as of v2.1). They are going to fix it.